# How can we change EditingStyle Button's height with respect to the tableVIew cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using TableView and on swiping the cell with editing style .delete but the size of cell has been customized as per the requirements of app. the delete Button height is little bigger how can we customize that.

Check the screenshot please:

[image]

Comment: plz see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022696/custom-uitableviewrowaction-button/42023205#42023205

Answer (score 1):

**@averydev** update my code in swift you can try this

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func didTransition(to state: UITableViewCellStateMask) {
            super.willTransition(to: state)
            if state == .showingDeleteConfirmationMask {
                let deleteButton: UIView? = subviews.first(where: { (aView) -> Bool in
                    return String(describing: aView).contains("Delete")

                })
                if deleteButton != nil {
                    deleteButton?.frame.size.height = 50.0
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: but it shows error  does not override any method from its superclass

Comment: @MayankWadhwa are you useing uitableviewcell custom class or not ?

Comment: @balkaransingh, what to do if I don't have delete button but using UISwipeActionsConfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, in iOS 16, the way to do it is by calling the **willBeginEditingRowAt** table view delegate method in your view controller class and changing the **height** property of the **UISwipeActionPullView**. I'm going to refer to your view controller class as NotesViewController here:

```
class NotesViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    extension NotesViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            // Get the subviews of the table view
            let subviews = tableView.subviews

            // Iterate through subviews to find _UITableViewCellSwipeContainerView
            for subview in subviews {

                if String(describing: type(of: subview)) == "_UITableViewCellSwipeContainerView" {

                    // Get the UISwipeActionPullView
                    if let swipeActionPullView = subview.subviews.first {

                        if String(describing: type(of: swipeActionPullView)) == "UISwipeActionPullView" {

                            // Set the height of the swipe action pull view (set to whatever height your custom cell is)
                            swipeActionPullView.frame.size.height = 50

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```